# excel Dmax returning cell location

Tags: excel, vba, location, max, formula

I've seen here some posts related with my problem, but no one mentions my "real" problem. Here i want to return the address of the max "Total de Nok's" that match the criteria "777777777".

Without the "ADDRESS", it gives always the correct answer (the nº, not the address). The issue is that if there are 2 or more equal numbers in Col H (Total de Nok's), it only return the address of the 1st even if it don't match the criteria.

The example on the image shows that this formula returns H2 instead of H4 as it should be.

Can someone help me out ? How can i get the cell address meeting the criteria "777777777" ?

```
=ADDRESS(DMAX(D1:H10000; "Total de Nok's";J1:J2 );8)
```

[Here's the table :][2]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDaWs.jpg

Tkx in advance.

Comment: Your problem is that the `DMAX` function always returns a **value**, not a cell reference. Wrapping this function inside an `ADDRESS` doesn't change the `DMAX` function to return a reference. It's still a value. So the `$H$1` reference you think you're getting is really column=8 (which is "H", because that's what you put in the `ADDRESS` function) and row=1 (because that's the **value** that `DMAX` returns). Change the values in your "Total de Nok's" column and you'll see the address "reference" change. You'll need to find another way to get the address if you really need it.

Comment: Tkx PeterT. I figured that out already. :( Is there another way ? Don't MUST be with a similar formula. I just want to get cell reference of the highest value (witch is always bigger than the last with the same Tlm 1) with the condition 777777777.

Comment: Why is the cell reference necessary?

Comment: Hi Peter! I was going on the wrong way. My goal was to detect the cell to change his color when meet the criteria. I realize now that is as simple as a "conditional format". So dumb of me. It's done. Thanks for trying to help and waste your time, Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by doing a conditional format in cell.